# What is the remainder of $7^m\times 19^n$ divided by 16500.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

This question recomends me to compute $\varphi (16500)$ and use it to solve the problem. However, I can not see how it helps. Once $$\varphi (16500)=\varphi (2^2\cdot3\cdot5^3\cdot11)=(2^2-2)(3-1)(5^3-5^2)(11-1)=4000$$
leads to $7^{4000}\equiv 1 \pmod{16500}$ and $19^{4000}\equiv 1 \pmod{16500}$ and we may conclude that $(7\cdot19)^{4000}\equiv 1 \pmod{16500}$.

For small values of $n$ and $m$ we simply have $7^m\times 19^n$ itself as the remainder. I think $4000$ is a too great exponent to help us control values for $m$ and $n$ somehow.

Any hint suffices.

Comment: What's the remainder when divided by $2^2$? How about $11$?

Comment: I suspect that the problem composer intends that you provide a function $~f(m,n) ~: ~\Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}^2 \to \{0,1,2,\cdots, 16499\}~$ such that $~7^m \times 19^n \equiv f(m,n) \pmod{16500}.~~$ If my suspicion happens to be right, then the function will necessarily be convoluted.  You might then consider interrogating the residues of $~7^m~$ and $~19^n~$ against the various modulos of $~2^2, ~3^1, ~5^3, ~11^1.~$  Then, having done that, you would (apparently) have to use something like the Chinese Remainder Theorem to then construct the overall function $~f(m,n).~$

Comment: Re my previous comment, the first question that I would ask myself is: when interrogating $~a^b~$ against $~p^k ~: ~p ~$ prime, what is the smallest positive integer $~r,~$ such that $\displaystyle ~a^r \equiv 1\pmod{p^k}.~$

Comment: Please give some context that indicates what type of answer is expected (e.g. in some courses an efficient algorithm might be considered an answer).

Comment: I think it want us to find the range of the function mentioned by @user2661923 according to values of $m$ and $n$. By Euler we already know that when $m=n=4000$ the remainder is $1$.

Comment: Actually, the remainder is 1 for all values of $m$ and $n$ that are multiples of 4000 at the same time. But there might be a smaller exponent that would make the remainder be 1 as well, as @user2661923 mentioned in their last comment. But if there is, that exponent is a divisor of 4000 for sure.

Comment: I just noticed that using that fact, if we fix $m=4000k$ then $7^m\cdot19^n$ gives remainders 19, 361 and 6859 when $1\leqslant n\leqslant3$. Similarly, if we fixed $n=4000k$, then $7^m\cdot19^n$ gives remainders 7, 49, 343, 2401 and 307 when $1\leqslant m\leqslant5$. The remainder 307 is in the range because it's easy to see that $7^5\equiv 307 \pmod{16500}$. Now at least we already know some values of the range.

Comment: Carmichael totient brings it down a lot...